# How to store number of specific characters from a matrix into another vector in R

Tags: r

```
> f
[,1] [,2] [,3] 
[1,] "A"  "B"  "A"
[2,] "B"  "B"  "B"
[3,] "B"  "B"  "C"
```

Let's consider that I have generated a matrix like the one above. I want to store  the number of specific characters (eg: "B") from the above matrix into a separate vector.

I am expecting a result like this:

```
f_B
[1] 2 3 1
```

f_B is another vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `colSums` on the logical `matrix`

```
f_B <- colSums(f == "B")
f_B
#[1] 2 3 1
```

---

If we need to get the frequency of each unique element for each of the columns

```
table(f, col(f))      
#f   1 2 3
#  A 1 0 1
#  B 2 3 1
#  C 0 0 1
```

#### data

```
f <- structure(c("A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "C"), 
  .Dim = c(3L, 3L))
```

Comment: User of `table` is even more elegant.

Comment: @MKR  Thanks. I was checking your answer and then thought to update in case anybody needed

Answer (score 2):

You can have vector for all elements using `sapply` on `unique` elements of matrix as:

```
t(sapply(unique(as.vector(f)),function(x)colSums(f==x)))

#   [,1] [,2] [,3]
# A    1    0    1
# B    2    3    1
# C    0    0    1
```

**Note:** The above solution is sight extension to the answer provided by `@akrun`

**Data:**

```
f <- matrix(data = c("A","B","A","B","B","B","B","B","C"), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 3)
```